# how to use 2 functions at once in delphi?

Tags: delphi

OK, so here is what i mean since i couldnt think of a better title, I have 2 editbox's. 1 is for input of a string and the other is for the output.

ive been experimenting with `edit2.text := LowerCase (edit1.text);`  & `edit2.text := ReverseString (edit1.text);`

i want to use the functions LowerCase & ReverseString at the same time so it both converts the capitals string to lowercase and reverses it also.. i just cant figure out how to do this without throwing all kinds of compiler errors, can anyone help me out

Comment: Both at the same time? So you want multithread? sure?

Comment: Forget `&` as anything except a way to provide a shortcut to a button or menu item in the `Caption` in Delphi. There's only one way to use it as an operator, and chances of you needing that one way are small. The equivalent of VB's `&` operator in Delphi is `and` for binary and logical comparisons and `+` for string concatenation (`Result := 'abc' + `def';`.

Comment: I hold my down-vote because it's such a common thing to do in any programming language. Not understanding why anyone would have up-voted this. I haven't written a single project yet that didn't do this.

Comment: @JerryDodge - I believe this question would be beneficial to anyone searching for this that doesn't know as they would end up here. He didn't know and that is why he asked! I am upvoting just to cancel out your down vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do

```
Edit2.Text := ReverseString(LowerCase(Edit1.Text));
```

Alternatively, since these functions commute, you can do

```
Edit2.Text := LowerCase(ReverseString(Edit1.Text));
```

Comment: Thank you.. that is exactly what i needed!  Yes, what do you call it when you do that? when you use ( ( )) ??

Comment: @Sheep: Function composition (but it's so 'obvious' you never talk about it, really). If `f` and `g` are functions that take a string and return a string, then `f('test')` is a string [because `f` returns a string], just as `'test'` is! Hence, just as you can compute `g('test')`, you can compute `g(f('test'))`.

Answer (score 4):

How about `edit2.text := LowerCase(ReverseString(edit1.text))` ?

Comment: Yes, what do you call it when you do that? when you use ( ( )) ??